# Is this a correct method for proving that $A - B\subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am not sure how to prove this because by definition, $A - B = \{x: x\in A | x\not\in B\}$.

So we know by definition that there is an element or elements of set $A$ in set $A - B$.

Maybe I could formally show this as: suppose $x\in(A - B)$, then $x\in A$. If $x\in A$, then $A - B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Are you actually being asked to prove this?  Okay.  Just use the definition literally: $\require{cancel}$ "suppose x∈(A−B), then x∈A $\color{blue}{\text{(because }x\in A\text{ and}a\not \in B\text{) }}$ . $\cancel{\text{If}}\color{blue}{\text{since}}$  x∈A $ \color{blue}{\text{and x was arbitrary}}$, then A−B⊆A" will do just fine.

Comment: "So we know by definition that there is an element or elements of set A in set A−B"  It's not that *some* of the elements of $A$ are in $A-B$.   It's that ***ALL*** of the elements of $A-B$ are in $A$.  It's not just that there are some elements of $A$ in $A-B$.  It's that the is NOTHING BUT elements of $A$ in $A-B$.

Comment: A proof can also just be an written  argument in words:  To be a subset of $A$ all the elements of $A-B$ must be elements of $A$.  As the definition of $A-B$ is all the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$, it is part of the the definition that all elements of $A-B$ be elements of  $A$.  So $A-B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: yes we are lol. what does the little a represent here? did you mean for that to be x? does "a" represent an element of set A here I am guessing

Comment: I meant for it to be an $x$.  I was actually just trying to cut and paste what you said as what you said was essentially correct.